# Yii2 - Insert/Update database values dynamically by detecting data changes

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I would like to detect changes in database based on user input. Feasibly, I should detect new or existing values in database by id.

Basically, I would like to dynamically detect an update of the latest user input and eliminate updating ones that is untouched.

Example :

- Skillset - A, B, C (insert since it is new)
- On update, skillset (B, C, D)
- I will remove A and insert D instead, not updating B and C

My database is storing per row for every skill.

Example :

- User A - Skill A
- User A - Skill B
- User A - Skill C
- User B - Skill A
- User B - Skill B

Form :

```
$skills = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['id', 'name'])
->from('skillset')
->all();

foreach ($skills as $skill) {
echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=\"skill[]\" value='$skill[id]' /> $skill[name]<br>";
    }
}

?>

<br/>
<div class="form-group" style="float:right">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
$skills = Yii::$app->request->post('skill');

$model = $this->findModel($id);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    foreach ($skills as $skill) { 
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
        ->insert('skillsetassignment', [
        'staff_id' => $id,
        'skillset_id' => $skill,
        ])->execute();
    }
}
```

Is there an built-in method in Yii2 that handles such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove all for user and insert new rows again.

The other way, more elegant, will be playing with set operations and `array_diff()`. Next an example from a personal project:

```
$removed_workers_ids = array_diff($initial_workers, $new_workers);
$included_workers_ids = array_diff($new_workers, $initial_workers);
```

- `$initial_workers` is an array with ids of the workers existing at the  beginning of the request, the old ones.
- `$new_workers` is an array with the ids of the workers selected on the request
- `array_diff()` makes the magic
- delete all rows with ids included on `$removed_workers_ids`
- insert the ones in `$included_workers_ids`

Also check this out: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#upsert()-detail